# Can't create Azure SQL Database in Australia

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a Azure SQL Database located in Australia Southeast.  The problem is when I go to create a new server the Australian location (and others ) are missing from the location drop down.

Here is what I see on the Azure portal.  I can create other resources (Web app) in Australia without a problem.

Any help would be great

Comment: This is something you'll need to as Azure support about. Nothing can be done here. Just open a billing ticket.

Answer (score 8):

Some subscriptions have restrictions on creating Compute and SQL resources in certain regions. The behavior you noticed was expected due to the subscription type and is not a service degradation. We are working on better communicating such region restriction information to make it clearer. We apologize for any confusion this might have caused.

Disclaimer: I am a Program Manager for Microsoft, working on SQL Server

Comment: What if someone start with Trial but later on convert their subscription then what's going to happen how long it will take Australia East appear in that list?

Comment: @DanRediske Can you please provide any link which covers this? Or where you go in the Azure Portal to configure it?

Comment: But why and why is this not documented anywhere?? Wasting hours of time trying to figure out why it's not working

Comment: @GFoley83 - I cannot; I no longer work for Microsoft and thus I no longer support this product and have direct access to the engineering team to confirm this is still the behavior- it never had a source beyond my internal contacts. I would suggest that you either open a support ticket or select a different region (or do so in the meantime). 

After reviewing the pricing page myself- it would lead me to believe that you should see the Australia DCs as options- but my guess is that you either have or started with a Trial subscription and that was a user experience that was never resolved.

Answer (score -3):

Please have a look here. Even the Azure Management portal has both the Australian locations.
[image: Australian Locations]

Comment: Just because you have a Pay-As-You-Go subscription, If you have a trial account but then you convert to Pay-As-You-Go you can not see Australia East in that list.